# Getting data from vbulletin database that writing in Hebrew, getting weird encoding

Tags: php, mysql, json, vbulletin

Hello I'm trying to make an API for my forum, I'm getting data through the sql of the forum and when trying to get a post with hebrew in it it has some weird encoding, I cant figuring it out

```
{"status":"success","data":{"title":"ֳ—ג€˜ֳ—ג€ֳ—ג„¢ֳ—ֲ§ֳ—ג€ 2","text":"ֳ—ֲ©ֳ—ג€ֳ—ג€™ֳ—ֲ©ֳ—ג€ֳ—ג€™ֳ—ֲ©ֳ—ג€ֳ—ג€™ֳ—ֲ©ֳ—ג€ֳ—ג€™ֳ—ֲ©ֳ—ג€ֳ—ג€™ֳ—ֲ©ֳ—ג€ֳ—ג€™","creator":"Name","messages_count":"3"}}
```

thats an example of return after make it encoding it to json but its looks the same after printing it directly from the sql.

thats how I encoding :

```
echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "data" => $data), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I can't figure out whats the problem in here and how can I get data from sql on vbulletin

- The vbulletin print the hebrew well after getting it from the sql I have tried to figure out how they did that but I couldn't
- Sorry for my bad english.